# How to fetch random data from Firebase from Parent and its children

Tags: android, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to display random images, Quotes (Data) from the firebase real-time database just like sql data base order by asc,desc,RAND ( ).

How can I do this firebase real time database by short line of code.

```
databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Quotes").orderby ????;
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is one way of getting data randomly its not perfect though,
[Reference for this code by peter(answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47169190/get-random-data-android-firebase-database-in-recyclerview)

```
databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Quotes");
databaseReference .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            int ads = (int) dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
            int rand = new Random().nextInt(ads);
            for(DataSnapshot data: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
            for(DataSnapshot datas: data.getChildren()){
            for(int i = 0; i < rand; i++) {
    
            list = new ArrayList<your-class-method-for-holding data>();
    
                Yourclass value = datas.getValue(yourclass.class);
                //Use your class to get the data and display it on your views
                //in this loop  
                
    
    }}}}
```